# JsonIter Scala - Format macro

Tags: scala, macros, deserialization

In Play Json you can use this macro `Jsonx.formatInline` for example, which inlines the json object to its json property. Is there any approach to achieve this using jsoniter library?
For instance, in this code:

```
case class Foo(values : String)
case class WrapperOfFoo(val : rapperOfFoo)
val codec : JsonValueCodec[[WrapperOfFoo]] = JsonCodecMaker.make
val messageFoo = new Foo("test")
val message = new WrapperOfFoo(messageFoo)
val json = writeToArray(message)(codec).map(_.toChar).mkString
println(json)
```

The result is:

```
{
  "val": {
    "values": "test"
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "val" : "test"
}
```

Since it's just a wrapper that has only one property, I want it to be inlined, is there a way to achieve this in JsonIter?

Comment: I took a look at the source code, and this is not probably supported (I didn't read the whole code base, but there was no such macro in the library), although, you can try to define some implicit class or something which provides some generic functionality to the JsonCodec's but that's not a reliable approach actually, so maybe try implementing it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a complement to my comment (about the implicit class), this is kind of what I meant:

```scala
implicit class CodecOps[A](codec: JsonValueCodec[A]) {
    def encodeBy[B](mapFunc: A => B)(implicit bCodec: JsonValueCodec[B]): JsonValueCodec[A] =
      new JsonValueCodec[A] {
        override def decodeValue(in: JsonReader, default: A): A = codec.decodeValue(in, default)

        override def encodeValue(x: A, out: JsonWriter): Unit =
          bCodec.encodeValue(mapFunc(x), out)

        override def nullValue: A = codec.nullValue
      }

    def decodedBy[B](contraMapFunc: B => A)(implicit bCodec: JsonValueCodec[B]): JsonValueCodec[A] =
      new JsonValueCodec[A] {
        override def decodeValue(in: JsonReader, default: A): A =
          contraMapFunc(bCodec.decodeValue(in, bCodec.nullValue))

        override def encodeValue(x: A, out: JsonWriter): Unit = codec.encodeValue(x, out)

        override def nullValue: A = codec.nullValue
      }
  }

// And then inside your models, assuming implicit JsonValueCodec[Foo] is defined earlier
implicit val codec : JsonValueCodec[FooWrapper] = JsonCodecMaker.make[FooWrapper]
    .encodeBy(_.foo)
    .decodedBy(FooWrapper.apply)
    

println(json)
// result => {"values":"test"}
println(readFromString[FooWrapper]("{\"values\":\"test\"}"))
// result => FooWrapper(Foo(test))
```

Note that this is the same behavior in `Jsonx.formatInline`, so it doesn't return `{"value": "test"}`. Imagine this way, what happens if `Foo` was a complex structure? what key should `value` get replaced with?

Comment: 10x!!!It helped me a lot

Comment: And what if we need to do somethin more complex , with underscore like to represent multiple values like this  { "WrapperOfFoo_Foo" : "test"} ?

Comment: @Romanmargolin I didn't quite understand you question, can you provide some example code?

Comment: Thanks for help first of all
```
case class Foo(complicatedFoo : compliactedFoo)
case class ComplicatedFoo(complicatedFooV1: ComplicatedFooV1, complicatedFooV2: ComplicatedFooV2)
case class ComplicatedFooV1(value : String)
case class ComplicatedFooV2(value: String)
```
And json to be : {
"ComplicatedFoo_ComplicatedFooV1": "value",
"ComplicatedFoo_ComplicatedFooV2": "value",
}

Comment: This is quite different from what you asked in the question, in this case you want to flatten all the objects, and you expect the keys to be concatenation of the field name with class name, this needs a recursive approach and maybe some reflections! the `formatInline` just drops the first layer (flattens once, and doesn't change any key).